# class for reciving sms not work

Tags: android, eclipse, sms, android-broadcastreceiver

I used this code for block sms revised. but when I installed it on my phone and receive a sms log not printed in logcat. i think this class is not run when a sms is received. here I add BroadcastReceiver class and manifest.

```
public class SmsFilter extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.i("LOG","check if this class runs or not");




    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[])extras.get("pdus");

            if (pdus.length < 1) return; // Invalid SMS. Not sure that it's possible.

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (sender == null) sender = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                String text = message.getMessageBody();
                if (text != null) sb.append(text);
            }

            Log.i("payam: ", "sms recived");
            Log.i("payam: ", sender);



            if (sender != null &&  Search.search(sender)==true) {


                 abortBroadcast();

            }
            return;
        }
    }

    // ...
}




 }
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="block.list"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity

        android:name=".FirstPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<receiver android:name=".receiver.SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>


    <activity

        android:name=".Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name=".BlockActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SmsFilter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".CustomAdapter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add following permissions -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Here's a working tutorial [Link](http://androidexample.com/Incomming_SMS_Broadcast_Receiver_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=62&aaid=87)